# Python Data to Dict handling

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, gurobi

maybe a trivial question but i am really struggling. (Update, fixed to provide what i wanted, but very open to more efficient formulations)

i have this DF:

```
                      Base_Node Turbine_1 Turbine_2 Charging_Station_1
0           Base_Node       0.0       1.1       5.3               23.5
1           Turbine_1       1.1       0.0       4.2               23.4
2           Turbine_2       5.3       4.2       0.0               22.8
3  Charging_Station_1      23.5      23.4      22.8                0.0
```

which describes the cost of going from node i to j:
I have writen a function that transforms this into a dict successfully. However since im working on a delivery and pick up variant where each (node) should be 2 nodes, one delivery and one pick-up. And for the model to work easier i need the base node (delivery-orgin / pickup-destination) to be in the index 0 and 2n+1, while turbines and chargers have delivery 1...n and pick-up n...2n, where the relation between pick-up and delivery is i and i+n.

```
def matrix_to_dict(cost_df):
    cost_of_route = {}
    for row in range(cost_df.shape[0]):  # Loop through rows
        for col in range(1, cost_df.shape[1]):  # Start from 1 to exclude first column
            cost_of_route[(row, col-1)] = cost_df.iloc[row, col]

    return cost_of_route
```

this makes good dicts but dont take into account that its double up with nodes,

Have fix the problem with this code, it but seems inefficient, but i am not so experienced, so very open for suggestions:

```
def matrix_to_dict(cost_df,n):
    
    cost_of_route = {}
    
    for row in range(0, 1):  # Loop through rows
        for col in range(1, cost_df.shape[1]):  # Start from 1 to exclude first column
            cost_of_route[(row, col-1)] = cost_df.iloc[row, col]

    for row in range(0, 1):  # Loop through rows
        for col in range(1, cost_df.shape[1]-1):  # Start from 1 to exclude first column
            cost_of_route[(row, col+n)] = cost_df.iloc[row, col+1]
    
    for row in range(0, cost_df.shape[0]):  # Loop through rows
        for col in range(1, 2):  # Start from 1 to exclude first column
            cost_of_route[(row, col-1)] = cost_df.iloc[row, col]
    
    for row in range(0, cost_df.shape[0]):  # Loop through rows
        for col in range(1, 2):  # Start from 1 to exclude first column
            cost_of_route[(row+n, col-1)] = cost_df.iloc[row, col]


    for row in range(1, cost_df.shape[0]):  # Loop through rows
        for col in range(2, cost_df.shape[1]):  # Start from 1 to exclude first column
            cost_of_route[(row, col-1)] = cost_df.iloc[row, col]
    
    for row in range(1, cost_df.shape[0]):  # Loop through rows
        for col in range(2, cost_df.shape[1]):  # Start from 1 to exclude first column
            cost_of_route[(row+n, col-1)] = cost_df.iloc[row, col]
            

    for row in range(1, cost_df.shape[0]):  # Loop through rows
        for col in range(2, cost_df.shape[1]):  # Start from 1 to exclude first column
            cost_of_route[(row, col-1+n)] = cost_df.iloc[row, col]
            
    for row in range(1, cost_df.shape[0]):  # Loop through rows
        for col in range(2, cost_df.shape[1]):  # Start from 2 to exclude first column
            cost_of_route[(row+n, col-1+n)] = cost_df.iloc[row, col]
            
   

    for row in range(0, 1):  # Loop through rows
        for col in range(2, cost_df.shape[1]):  # Start from 1 to exclude first column
            cost_of_route[(n+n+1, col-1+n)] = cost_df.iloc[row, col]
            # print(n+n+1, col-1+n)
            
    for row in range(0, 1):  # Loop through rows
            for col in range(2, cost_df.shape[1]):  # Start from 1 to exclude first column
                cost_of_route[(col-1+n, n+n+1)] = cost_df.iloc[row, col]
                # print(col-1+n, n+n+1) 
                

    for row in range(0, cost_df.shape[0]):  # Loop through rows
        for col in range(1, 2):  # Start from 1 to exclude first column
            cost_of_route[(row+n, col-1+n)] = cost_df.iloc[row, col]
           # print(row+n, col-1+n)
    for row in range(0, cost_df.shape[0]):  # Loop through rows
        for col in range(1, 2):  # Start from 1 to exclude first column
            cost_of_route[(col-1+n, row+n)] = cost_df.iloc[row, col]
           
   
    return cost_of_route
```

output as wanted:

{(0, 0): '0.0', (0, 1): '21.4', (0, 2): '26.4', (0, 3): '21.6', (0, 4): '21.4', (0, 5): '26.4', (0, 6): '21.6', (1, 0): '21.4', (2, 0): '26.4', (3, 0): '0.0', (4, 0): '21.4', (5, 0): '26.4', (6, 0): '21.6', (1, 1): '0.0', (1, 2): '5.0', (1, 3): '1.3', (2, 1): '5.0', (2, 2): '0.0', (2, 3): '5.0', (3, 1): '1.3', (3, 2): '5.0', (3, 3): '0.0', (4, 1): '0.0', (4, 2): '5.0', (4, 3): '21.4', (5, 1): '5.0', (5, 2): '0.0', (5, 3): '26.4', (6, 1): '1.3', (6, 2): '5.0', (6, 3): '21.6', (1, 4): '0.0', (1, 5): '5.0', (1, 6): '1.3', (2, 4): '5.0', (2, 5): '0.0', (2, 6): '5.0', (3, 4): '21.4', (3, 5): '26.4', (3, 6): '21.6', (4, 4): '0.0', (4, 5): '5.0', (4, 6): '1.3', (5, 4): '5.0', (5, 5): '0.0', (5, 6): '5.0', (6, 4): '1.3', (6, 5): '5.0', (6, 6): '0.0', (7, 4): '21.4', (7, 5): '26.4', (7, 6): '21.6', (4, 7): '21.4', (5, 7): '26.4', (6, 7): '21.6'}

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there expected output?